# Deleting Duplicated Lines In TEXT File?

Tags: regex, text-editors

I am trying to cleanup a text and for some reason every line duplicated 3 times am i able to get ride of duplicates with regex or tricks or do you know a software which could do that , text file is like this

```
Party Started 10:17 (89/1/2)
Party Started 10:17 (89/1/2)
Party Started 10:17 (89/1/2)
Jessica At Dinner 17:54 (89/1/2)
Jessica At Dinner 17:54 (89/1/2)
Jessica At Dinner 17:54 (89/1/2)
```

How can i clean it up , and get ride of duplicated lines , it's about 69,587 lines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `uniq`, standard with bash.
Just type:

```
uniq filewithdup.txt > filenew.txt
```

Comment: You can get uniq in windows through [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), or [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) - I prefer Gow, but gnuwin seems to have a more comprehensive toolset.

Answer (score 7):

Since you mention MS Office, I'll give you a native Windows solution.

If you are using Windows Vista or later, there's Windows PowerShell built in. You can use the command `Get-Unique`:

> The Get-Unique cmdlet compares each item in a sorted list to the next item, eliminates duplicates, and returns only one instance of each item. The list must be sorted for the cmdlet to work properly.

```
Get-Content input.txt | Get-Unique | Set-Content output.txt
```

If it's not sorted, you can use `Sort-Object -Unique` (it also works on already sorted input, but do *not* use if you do not wish to remove duplicates with other lines between them).

```
Get-Content input.txt | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content output.txt
```

Comment: I have both linux and windows , unix solution just worked but man i learned something , this powershell seems powerful , Thanks sir

Comment: @echolab PowerShell aliases many standard Linux and Windows commands, so you can do things like `ls` or `dir` and have it work. The arguments may be different, so `man <command>`, `help <command>` or `Get-Help <command>` are very useful. You can also use anything from the .NET Framework, so it is *very* powerful, but can be a little confusing. In this case, `cat input.txt | unique > output.txt` would also work.

Comment: You can also download PowerShell for XP

Answer (score 1):

Regex was tagged, so:

```
/(.+)\n\1/g
```

Comment: nope, gets false positives. `s/^(.*\n)\1+/\1/mg` on the whole thing, perhaps?

Comment: @sreservoir, Ah, definitely a good idea to look for multiple repeats. If you include the line break in the main match, then it won't match a repeat at the end of the file. Also, `.*` was giving me trouble and matching empty strings or word barriers, or something of the sort. Also, what do you mean about false positives? Can I have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Remove Duplicate Rows From A Text File Using Powershell](https://secretgeek.net/ps_duplicates)

---

We can write it with a batch file like this one :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Remove Duplicates Lines & Mode 75,3 & Color 0B
Set InputFile="%~1"
If [%Inputfile%] EQU [""] goto Usage
set "OutPut=%~n1_Unique.txt"
echo( & echo( Please Wait a while ...
Call :GetUnique %Inputfile% "%OutPut%"
If Exist "%OutPut%" Start "" /MAX "%OutPut%" & Exit
::--------------------------------------------
:GetUnique <InputFile> <OutPuFile>
Powershell -C "(gc '"%~1"').ToLower() | sort | get-unique >'"%~2"'"
Exit /B
::--------------------------------------------
:Usage 
echo( & echo( Drag and drop a file on this batch to remove duplicates
Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
Exit /B
::--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following regex in Notepad++

```
Find what: (?sm)(^[^\r\n]*)[\r\n](?=.*^\1)
Replace with: (blank)
check Wrap around
check Regular expression
DO NOT CHECK . matches newline
Click Replace All
```

Comment: Its always best to explain your answer, it enhances it.