# Remove similar strings from text?

Tags: notepad++

i'm using **notepad++** and **sed** on Windows.
I have a file text *2000+* lines but sometimes i have this rows:

```
http://www.shragle.com/files/9baa908b/Bvdub-The_First_Day-%2528HN031%2529-2012.rar
http://www.shragle.com/files/9baa908b/Bvdu...1%2529-2012.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005_-_Candlemass.part1.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005...emass.part1.rar
http://www.filefactory.com/file/a181d18/n/...nimal_2010_.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152136400/2005_-_Candlemass.part2.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152136400/2005...emass.part2.rar
http://www.shragle.com/files/3e0f3488/Cesa...testHits2CD.rar
```

How can i remove this rows?

```
http://www.shragle.com/files/9baa908b/Bvdu...1%2529-2012.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005...emass.part1.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152136400/2005...emass.part2.rar
```

I don't want remove this rows:

```
http://www.shragle.com/files/3e0f3488/Cesa...testHits2CD.rar
http://www.filefactory.com/file/a181d18/n/...nimal_2010_.rar
```

because this rows are unique and valid for me, i want remove only similar rows

Similar rows, i want delete the **...** line

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005_-_Candlemass.part1.rar
http://rapidshare.com/files/152133956/2005...emass.part1.rar
```

unique row because in my text file is presented only one time:

```
http://www.filefactory.com/file/a181d18/n/...nimal_2010_.rar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting Duplicated Lines In TEXT File?](http://superuser.com/questions/440889/deleting-duplicated-lines-in-text-file)

Comment: There's no NPP solution in the possible duplicate, but there's some regex that may work in `sed`. There's also a native Linux (with Windows ports) and native Windows solution that are easier.

Comment: If you only want to remove *similar* rows as opposed to exact duplicates, could you describe your criteria for removal? What qualifies a row for removal?

Comment: mmm..if u look if you look closely i want remove not duplicate lines, but a *type* of lines. I want to delete the lines that are not really unique. *http://www.shragle.com/files/9baa908b/Bvdu* is present on two lines then the 2nd row continues with **...** I want eliminate **...** rows

Comment: How many characters at the start of two lines have to be equal so you consider them similar?

Comment: Alternatively, could you split it into sites so we can consistently match up to a number of slashes? From your examples, we can match up to the 5th `/` to match the hashes, but this will vary by site, so unless you don't have any other sites... (pinging @Dennis)

Comment: I consider similar until it arrives on `...`

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Candlemass. I like Nightwish, Rammstein, and E Nomine, so I'll check out Candlemass. `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will delete a line if its first 40 characters are identical to those of a former:

```
Find what:         ((?<=\n)|^)([^\n]{40})([^\n]*\n)(.*\n)?\2[^\n]*($|\n)
Replace with:      \2\3\4
Search Mode:       Regular expression
. matches newline: checked
```

You might have to click `Replace All` more than once.

#### How it works

- `((?<=\n)|^)` checks if the rest of the regular expression is preceded by a newline or the beginning of the file.
- `([^\n]{40})([^\n]*\n)` matches the first 40 characters of a line (stored in `\2`) and the rest of it (stored in `\3`).
- `(.*\n)?` is any number of lines (stored in `\4`).
- `\2[^\n]*` is a line beginning with the same 40 characters.
- `($|\n)` checks if the rest of the regular expression is followed by a newline or the end of the file.

If this pattern is encountered, there's a line similar to `\2\3`.

By replacing all by `\2\3\4`, that similar line gets deleted.

Comment: But i write this regex `((?<=\n)|^)([^\n]{40})([^\n]*\n)(.*\n)\2[^\n]*($|\n)` on *Notepad++* or *sed*? On notepad++ doesn't work

Comment: I wrote it for Notepad++ with the new regex engine. The expression was missing a `?`. It should work now.

Comment: thank you!, now it works..but it works only if the similar rows are one below the other. Is a regex to detect this type of string in random order?

Comment: yeah,the regex works well, but How I find these similar lines when these lines are in scattered order ?. How do I detect them? Which regex must i use for similar strings in random order?

Comment: Dennis, Look here please: http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/8539/regexproblem.png

Comment: But if i order the lines placing them one above the other your regex works (same string as before) http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/1893/regexorder.png

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have to check `. matches newline`. It's `. significa 'a capo'` in your version.